# I'm getting a HTTP Status 404 error in my servlet programm

Tags: java, html, forms, servlets, configuration

[this is the servlet code that i have written](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1q7B.png)
[this is an html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/118Lf.png)
[this is the web.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2MyH.png)
[this is the 404 status code that i'm getting after running the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLSB3.png)

I tried changing the url-pattern,package name still its giving request resource not available.

Comment: Are you able to start your server? At which port it is running? What is the URL you are hitting? What does pom.xml contains?